# Angular Changed Url And Change Component

Tags: angular8

I have a component in Angular and when I press a button I want Ural to change
But I do not want my component to change
What do you think I should do?

Comment: hi saeed, could you please show some code of what you've tried or what you have so far?

Comment: I have an overview on this issue I use RouterOutlet And I want the Url to change But I do not want my component to change